# Add files to LAST commit Pushed on Github Branch

Tags: git, github

I've just pushed a commit onto Github but forgot to add 2 files to it

How do I take it back and add the files without making second commit ?

Does `git commit --amend --no-edit` work on a commit already pushed to remote ?

Comment: You would have to force push the amended commit to the remote. If you're collaborating with other people via that remote, this could cause problems.

Comment: it is a team project but I am 100% the only one working on this branch which commands would I have to execute ?

Comment: Use `--force-with-lease` in this case, rather than `--force` (even though if you're indeed the only one working on the branch it's probably superfluous, but a good practice)

Comment: ok so `git push --force-with-lease` ? what does `-with-lease` do ? 

Comment: [`git help push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are correct: you must force-push the result.  The reason is that `git commit --amend` does not actually *change* a commit, because commits *cannot be changed* (not even by Git itself).  What `git commit --amend` does is *kick one commit off the end of a branch* while *making a new and improved commit to put at the end of the branch instead*.  The other Git repository involved will refuse to kick *their* commit (your commit, really) off the end of *their* branch to match.

#### A picture is worth some words

A picture makes this much clearer, in my opinion.  Let's draw commits like this:

```
<-H
```

These represent the commit itself—the internal Git object and all of its ancillary details—as an uppercase-letter-and-arrow.  The actual commit holds two things: a snapshot of all files, and some metadata.  Neither part can be changed at all.

The snapshot makes up an archive (much like a tar or rar or winzip archive).  Unlike a standard archive, though, the files are in a special, weird, Git-ized form, where they can be *shared* (de-duplicated).  Because they're read-only, it's safe for this commit to share, in storage, all the files that exactly match any file in any *other* commit.  (In fact, they can even be shared within a single commit, if the contents match.)

The metadata part of a commit holds stuff like your name and email address—as seen in your `user.name` and `user.email` setting—and the date-and-time-stamps for *when* you made the commit.  It holds your log message, where you write *why* you made the commit.  And, it holds for Git the hash ID of the *previous* commit: that's our arrow coming out of commit `H`.

What makes Git work—well, one part of what makes Git work, at least—is that each commit has one of these arrows, pointing to the *previous* commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

`H` "points to" (contains the raw hash ID of) earlier commit `G`.  `G`, being a commit, has both snapshot and metadata, and points to still-earlier commit `F`.  That commit has both snapshot and metadata, and so on.

This means that Git needs just the raw hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Git stores this last-commit-in-the-chain hash ID in a *branch name* such as `develop` or `feature/tall` or `main` or whatever:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

The *name* `main` *points to* the *last* commit `H`.  From there, Git can find all previous commits.

To add a new commit *on to the chain*, as we normally do, we first check out the desired commit-and-branch via the branch name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Git extracts all the (read-only, compressed, Git-ified, and de-duplicated / shared) files from `H` so that we can see them and work on and with them.  we do our work and `git add` our updates and run `git commit`, and Git packages up all the files into a new compressed/Git-ified/de-duplicated snapshot in a new commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

Commit `I` points back to `H` because `H` is our *current commit*.  (Commit `I` gets its unique hash ID during the writing-out operation; until then, we don't know what its hash ID will be, as that depends on the exact snapshot *and* the previous commit *and* the date and time *and* the log message: basically everything you're going to put in, some time in the future, but we don't know what or when until you've done it.)

As soon as commit `I` actually exists inside the repository, Git immediately *write's `I`'s new hash ID, whatever it turns out to be, into the current branch name*.  This means we now have:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

The *name* has changed.  The *new commit exists*.  No *existing commit* has been changed at all.  (This is why commits only point backwards: `H` can point to `G`, because `G` existed when we made `H`.  `H` can't point to `I` because until now, `I` did not exist, and we had no idea what hash ID it would get.  But `I` can point to `H`, because `H` exists when we make `I`.)

There's no reason to draw the bend in the graph any more, so we can draw this as:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and fit it all on one line.  (Using `git log --graph`, you'll see Git draws things vertically, with newer commits towards the top, instead of horizontally with newer commits towards the right.  Git also doesn't use single uppercase letters, of course, as that would limit us to 26 or so commits, depending on whose alphabet we use.)

What `git commit --amend` does is simple: it does not *change the existing commits* (it can't).  Instead, it attaches the *new* commit `I` to `H`'s *parent*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H
         \
          I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the name as usual.  We can't draw this graph without putting in the kink, but we *can* draw it like this:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

(The `--no-edit` option tells Git to copy the original commit message, and *don't* bring up the editor to let you change it.  The default is to copy the message but *do* bring up the editor.)

#### Why `--force` or `--force-with-lease` or similar

We now get to the interesting thing, which is why a force-push is required.

Whenever we make *new* commits, they exist *only in our own Git repository*.  But eventually we might want to give these commits to someone else.  So we have our Git call up some other Git software, somewhere, and send them our new commits—the ones we have that they don't, that they'll need.  After we've sent these commits, we have to *ask or tell them* to *create or update a branch name in **their** Git repository*.

That is, *they* may well have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main [in their Git repository]
```

in *their* repository.  We've added new commit `I`; they don't have it.

If we've added `I` to the end of `H`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- main [in our Git repository]
```

we'll send them `I` and then ask them to change their `main` to point to `I`.  They may check for permissions first (this is outside the Git code proper as it has no authentication model, but is done by hosting providers as an obviously-necessary add-on) and in general they'll say *okay* to this, because `I` simply *adds on*.  Commit `H` remains *reachable*.

But if we've made new commit `I` have commit `G` as its parent:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- main [in our Git repository]
```

and we ask them, politely, to make *their* name `main` point to commit `I`, they will refuse, on the grounds that if they did, they'd "lose" their commit `H`.  Git *finds* commits by starting from names, like `main`, and working backwards, and new commit `I` doesn't *find* commit `H`.  Once the commit is "lost", it might actually get removed entirely.  (Whether and when this happens is another, much more complicated question.)  So they just say *no, I won't do that because it would lose commits*, which in Git jargon is reported as a `non-fast-forward` error.

The thing is, we *want* them to drop commit `H`.  Commit `I` is our new-and-improved *replacement* for commit `H`.  To get them to understand that we do in fact mean *replace commit `H` with new and improved commit `I`*, we set the *force flag* on our `git push` operation.

There are several different ways to set the force flag.  One is unconditional, and it just turns the `git push` request into a command: *Here are some commits. And now: **I command you**, set your branch name _______ to hash ID _______!*

The reason to use `--force-with-lease` is that it offers a bit of safety.  Here, instead of a raw *set your branch* command, we have a conditional: *I believe your name _______ is set to hash ID _______.  If so, set it to _________ instead, even if that's a non-fast-forward!  Let me know what happened.*  Our Git gets the *expected* hash ID from our `origin/main` (assuming `git push origin` and other reasonable assumptions).  If we're in sync with them when we do this `git push --force-with-lease origin main`, the hash IDs will match up and, if we have the right permissions, they will obey our command and set their `main` to point to commit `I`, just as we want them to.